# 1960s science fiction short story alien explorer discovers robot uprising wiped out all humans leaving automated cities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, robots

Trying to find out the name of the story and the author. This would have appeared in the late 60's or very early 70s. I am pretty sure I read the story in Analog, Galaxy or one of the other science fiction magazines prevalent at the time. I believe the explorer was alien and also think his name was Wurz. He finds a domed city and is able to enter. While searching he discovers mass human graves and realizes that the robots running the city were the killers. The story ends with the explorer being "torn limb-from-limb" by the robots when he is discovered.